# Adjusting the colour fill of labels based on a conditional scale in ggplot

Tags: colors, conditional-statements, scale, gradient

I am using:
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

I have a quadrant scatterplot, with the values in each quadrant labelled with a different colour. I've achieved this using the following within ggplot2:

#Firstly I used case_when to mutate the object to create an identifying word for each quadrant

```
    mutate(class = case_when(overpm <= 0 & wicketspm <= 0 ~ 'hack',
                           overpm >= 0 & wicketspm >= 0 ~ 'star',
                           overpm >= 0 & wicketspm <= 0 ~ 'container',
                           overpm <= 0 & wicketspm >= 0 ~ 'breaker'))
```

#Then I used this word as the condition for which colour the label should be

```
    geom_label_repel(aes(label=bowler), size = 3, max.overlaps = Inf, fill = case_when(
    plotting$class == 'star' ~ "green",
    plotting$class == 'hack' ~ "red",
    plotting$class == 'container' ~ "lightblue",
    plotting$class == 'breaker' ~ "yellow"),
    force = 0.001)
```

This creates a plot that looks like this. The white eraser isn't part of it; the plot includes the names of real people so I thought it was better to erase the text for this post.

[screenshot of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGADb.png)

INSTEAD

I want to colour these labels using a colour scale. As values get closer to the top right corner, I want them to get greener. As values get closer to the bottom right corner, I want them to get more yellow. As values get closer to the bottom left corner, I want them to get redder. As values get closer to the top left corner, I want them to get more blue. I want values in the middle to be basically white. This picture is an example of this style of gradient; but I want the labels to be filled, not the background.

[screenshot of desired gradient effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2HQi.jpg)

I'm an R intermediate at best. I've looked through a lot of questions on here, and I haven't found anything that looks like it helps me. I have seen some solutions with a 2-colour scale, but nothing I felt I could implement. I realise I could do it myself by manually coding in hundreds more conditionals, but that would be painstaking. Apologies if the question has been answered elsewhere, I really did try.

I appreciate any help on how to achieve this solution.